# Best practise for naming conventions for entity fields and database table columns

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design, naming-conventions

i am using hibernate to create entities and database tables 
and i am confused about the naming conventions:

let's give an example:

we have a department entity as follows:

```
public class Department {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "department_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "{name.required}")
    @Size(max = 25, message = "{long.value}")
    @Column(name = "department_name", length = 25, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "department_admin_id", nullable = true)
    private Integer adminId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ik_parent_department_id")
    // set the generated column name
    private Department parentDepartment;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>(0);


}
```

what is the best when naming for example the **department admin** field, do you name the **column** as **department_admin_id** or **admin_id** and what about the **case** (lower/capital) ?

and when naming the **property**, what do you name it, **departmentAdminId** or **adminId** ?

please advise, what is the best practice in such case, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your table is called `department` then there's not much benefit in all it's columns beginning with `department_`. Just call them `id`, `name`, `admin_id`, etc.

After all, the members of you're class aren't prefixed in this way are they? The columns already have an implicit relation to `department` by being in the `department` table. Further explanation is over verbose and not needed.

**Edit:**
In java classes I would use camel case. For the column name I would seperate with underscores. Most DBs are case insensitive with table and column names.

Comment: so you are with not prefixing either the column or the property, and with camel case the property and underscore in columns (but what about the case in columns lower or upper?)

Answer (score 3):

I would go with Java-based properties and DB-based column names, so:

```
@Column(name = "FAVORITE_QUOTE")
private String favoriteQuote;
```

In OO-world you work with Java (camel-case) convention and in the same time you keep the DB convention (upper-case and underscore-linked). If you already have a DB schema generated, you'll typically need to adjust to this schema.

And if you're generating the schema - you don't want to annoy your future DBA ;-)

**EDIT:** I would prefer to go with `favoriteQuote` instead of `userFavoriteQuite` as I see it redundant. However, I've seen a lot of DB conventions in which prefixing the column with entity name somehow makes it easier for the DBA's to write queries.